# Storing Data in Global Var in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, global-variables, global

I am trying to save an array in global var.
I am calling an API that returns an array and I want to save it once when the code is starting and then use it all over the code.
I forgot to mention that I am building a WordPress plugin.
so this is my code:

```
function getCompanyDeatials()
{
    $email  = get_option('mail');

    $URL = "https://myapi/". "company?email=". $email;
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type:application/json; UTF-8'));
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $var = json_decode($result, true);
    $body = $var["body"];


    curl_close($curl);
    return $body;

}

add_action( 'init', 'my_run_only_once' );
function my_run_only_once() {
    
    if ( did_action( 'init' ) >= 2 )
        
        return;

    if( ! get_option('run_create_vip_order_once') ) {
       
       
        $company = getCompanyDeatials();
        upadte_post_meta(0,'company', $company );
        update_option( 'run_create_vip_order_once', true );
    }
}
```

the `getCompanyDeatials`is working, and also the `my_run_only_once` is running just once
but I can`t save it into global var ( i tired also to declare `global $company` and it didn't work)
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can use the `$GLOBALS` variable for managing global scope of data. If you need to use the variable `$company` outside the `my_run_only_once` you need to declare the variable outside the function, like `$company=""` and then use the `global $company` in each function that need to read/modify the variable. Read more here: https://www.php.net/language.variables.scope

Comment: I tried it already, didn`t work for me